# Bloquear un evento JS mientras termina una animación

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Tengo un carrusel el cual uso el evento `mousewheel DOMMouseScroll` para moverlo con la rueda del mouse, uso el siguiente condicional para detectar si se mueve la rueda hacia arriba o hacia abajo.

```
event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0
```

Funciona bien pero cuando muevo rápido la rueda del mouse ocurre muchas veces el evento y se buguea el carrusel.

Como puedo hacer para bloquear el evento se bloquee de alguna forma mientras finaliza la animación de mi carrusel.

Este el codigo completo del evento que llamo.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', "#"+id+" .element", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {

        remove_styles();
        $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+actual_record).addClass('previous');
        $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+new_element(1)).addClass('actual');
        $("#"+id+" .bullet ."+actual_record).addClass('active');

        var init = new_element(1);

        setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+init).addClass('card_next');}, 50);
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+init).addClass('next'); }    , 100);
        new_element(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        remove_styles();
        $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+actual_record).addClass('next');
        $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+new_element(-1)).addClass('actual');
        $("#"+id+" .bullet ."+actual_record).addClass('active');

        var init = new_element(-1);

        setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+init).addClass('card_previous');}, 50);
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#"+id+" .content_carrusel ."+init).addClass('previous');  }   , 100);
        new_element(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Por qué esos timeouts? Me parece que el problema está ahí

Comment: @PabloLozano Los necesito para que la transición salga bien, si no aparecen cada elemento de golpe

Comment: ¿Y esos 50 o 100 milisegundos se aprecian? Me parece que afectan al orden de ejecución y te descoloca todo. Aunque sin verlo funcionar no estoy 100% seguro

Comment: @PabloLozano Si se aprecian, aunque por ser tan poco uno pensaria que no pero son necesarios para que funcione como debe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre una solución en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263042/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-click-handler-in-jquery) del foro en ingles. Básicamente es el uso de la propiedad css `pointer-events`, de tal forma que el código quedaría de esta forma.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', "#"+id+" .element", function(event){
   $("#button_id").css("pointer-events", "none");

   // Codigo

   $("#button_id").css("pointer-events", "auto");
}
```

En mi caso tambien tuve que hacer un uso del `setTimeout` para retrasar 1 segundo. Pero esta solución me funciono como necesito